# changing default resizing property of subplot function of matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to show three different figure using subplot. One of them is are the original one and the other one is oversampled with factor of x. but subplot resize the oversampled image to fit and shows it as the original even though its size is about x times bigger than the original one. how can I change my code to show them in actual size.
this is my function:

```
function zp_over=zp_oversample(zp,fs,N,f)
% zp is my 2d image, fs is sampling frequency, N is dimension of image, f is used for scaling the sampling factor
    % Over-Sampling and plot
    x=round(fs/f);
    zp_ov = zeros(N*x); 
    zp_ov(1:x:end,1:x:end)=zp; 
    figure,subplot(121), imshow(zp_ov); title (' over sampled');
subplot(122);imshow(zp); % Original image
title('Original');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the 'position' option of the "subplot" function to manually specify the locations and sizes of the subplots.

For example:

```
figure;
subplot('Position', [0.35, 0.25, 0.5, 0.6]); % [left, bottom, width, height]
imshow(zp_ov);

subplot('Position', [0.35, 0.15, 0.5, 0.6]);
imshow(zp);
```

Of course, the exact values of the coordinates an sizes depend on the sizes of the images.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have three figure that one of them is bigger than two other figures. Is there other method? As you when the axes overlap. one of them has been chosen and to avoid it one has to have considerable gaps among figures that makes whole figure ugly.

Comment: In my experience, it all comes down to careful adjustment of the figure size, subplot positions and size through trial and error. You may decide to write a program to compute those values automatically. But if it is just a one-time thing, maybe the automaticity won't be worth the effort.